# CodeIgniter report error 500 when data is posted

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I have the following controller named admin

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id') || !$this->session->userdata('user_name'))
        {
            header("Location: /admin/login");
        }
        else
        {
            $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $user_name = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
            if (!$this->admin_model->verify($user_id, $user_name))
                header("Location: /admin/login");
        }
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['run'] = false;
        }
        else if (!$this->admin_model->loginverify($this->input->post('username'), 
                 $this->input->post('password')))
        {
            $data['run'] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['run'] = true;
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

And I have the following model called Admin_model

```
class Admin_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function verify($id, $name)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($id))
            return false;
        else
        {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id'=>$id, 'username'=>$name), 1);
            if ($query->result()->num_rows() === 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    public function loginverify($name, $pass)
    {
        $pass = md5($pass);
        //$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('username'=>$name, 'passwd'=>$pass), 1);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$name' AND passwd='$pass' LIMIT 1");
        if ($query->result()->num_rows() === 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

And my form is like the following:

```
<?php  if (!$run) 
{
?>
<form method="post" action="/admin/login">

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password</h5>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" id="submit" name ="submit" value="Login" /></div>

</form>
<?php

}else{
    echo "successfully login";
}
?>
```

I got a blank page when I submit, and when I inspect the network in Chrome, I see the post has caused a 500 internal server error.

When I change the direct query to get_where as in the above commented line, I got a severity 8192 with error message `mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.`

I am using manual form here but my CSRF is set to false. I've tried using `form_open('admin/login')` but then ridiculously it was turned to `localhost/?admin/login` with an extra `?`.

I have been running into all these problems here and I just don't know what I should do. I appreciate any help given.

Comment: What is your error_reporting setting?  500 likely means a fatal error, but you are able to see the E_DEPRECATED.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And you must have a `.htaccess` file.  Check your server's error_log for errors related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form is not pointing to a correct url maybe, so i sugget you to change this:

```
<form action="/admin/login">
```

to

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/login'); ?>">
```

then try replacing all the `headers() methods` :

```
header("Location: /admin/login");
```

with

```
redirect(site_url('admin/login'),'',302);
```

sincerily, never used `header();` with Codeigniter